# adding options after query parameters apache camel spring DSL

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I am trying to do a get request to the following url:

http://hellostackexchange?mynameiskees.json

the problem is that i don't see how i can add the option parameters after i have added the query parameters to the uri. My attempt is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
   <route id="hello stackexchange">
       <from uri="timer://counting_camera?fixedRate=true&amp;period=1000" />
       <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpQuery">
       <simple>"mynameiskees.json"</simple>
        </setHeader>
       <to uri=http4://hellostackexchange/>
       <to uri = "direct:test"/>
   </route>

   <route id = "final">
    <from uri="direct:test?authUsername=kees&amp;authPassword=kees"/>
    <to uri="log:result"/>
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

this results in the error:

```
There are 2 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri 
if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the 
endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{authPassword=kees, authUsername=kees}]
```

any tips on how to do this?

Comment: Direct does not have those parameters. You can put them into the headers or add them as properties of the message/exchange.

Comment: i solved this thanks to this comment thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Withe the help of @Namphibian i did the following, you can just add your query parameters to a header and add the options to your uri:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
   <route id="hello stackexchange">
       <from uri="timer://counting_camera?fixedRate=true&amp;period=1000" />
       <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpQuery">
           <simple>"mynameiskees.json"</simple>
       </setHeader>
       <to uri="http4://hellostackexchange?authUsername=kees&amp;authPassword=kees"/>
       <to uri = "log:result"/>
   </route>
</camelContext>
```